# AWS Batch doesnt find script in docker container but works when ran localy

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, aws-batch

So I have a dockerfile and  create an image from it that I need to use to run a script from aws batch, I've made the compute environment, the job definition and the job queue, and when I run the job it returns an error like this:

```
CannotStartContainerError: ResourceInitializationError: failed to create new container runtime task: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "mnt/app/export_script.sh": stat mnt/app/export_script.sh: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Here is the dockerfile for reference:

```
FROM oraclelinux:8

ARG release=19
ARG update=20

RUN  dnf -y install oracle-release-el8 && \
     dnf install unzip && \
     dnf -y install oracle-instantclient${release}.${update}-basic oracle-instantclient${release}.${update}-devel oracle-instantclient${release}.${update}-tools oracle-instantclient${release}.${update}-sqlplus && \
     rm -rf /var/cache/dnf

RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" && unzip awscliv2.zip && ./aws/install

WORKDIR /app

COPY /scripts/* /app/ 

RUN chmod +x /app/export_script.sh /app/import_script.sh

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/${release}.${update}/client64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ENV PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/${release}.${update}/client64/bin:$PATH

CMD [ "/bin/bash", "./export_script.sh" ]
```

I have tried running the image in a container through the docker desktop app and it has no problem finding the script (although the script does not work since its not connected to aws).
[image: Here you can see the lines with ORACLE codes that are run from the script]

Honestly I have no clue why this is happening and I've tried changing the docker file and the CMD or the command that the job parses to any possible thing, but it still returns the same type of error.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
CMD [ "/bin/bash", "./export_script.sh" ]
```

runs the script from the current directory.

The working directory can be overridden in Docker by using `docker run -w` to start the container. Apparently Batch is doing something to this effect and sets the working directory to `mnt/app`

Use the absolute path to your script in your dockerfile:

```
CMD [ "/bin/bash", "/app/export_script.sh" ]
```

and make sure the script supports it.

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer, but it does not seem to be the problem, i tried with that change already and it still works in local and it still doesnt work on aws batch. Quite honestly Im looking for other options to do the process rn.

Comment: @arthur248: when you run it locally, do you have any bind mounts set up?

Comment: Can you post the Batch job definition JSON?